# The expression for spin-orbit coupling in tight binding model

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter

I'm trying to obtain the Rashba spin-orbit coupling term in 2D for square lattice from the original expression $$H_{\text{so}}=\alpha \int d^3r \Psi^{\dagger}(\mathbf{r}) (\sigma _{y}p_{x}-\sigma _{x}p_{y})\Psi(\mathbf{r})$$
I think I have to expand the field operators $\Psi(\mathbf{r})$ in terms of Wannier functions $\Psi(\mathbf{r})=\sum_{i} c_{i}\phi_{\mathbf{R_i}}(\mathbf{r}) $and then to get expression: $$H^{'}_{\text{so}}=\alpha\sum_{<i,j>} c_{i}^{\dagger }\mathbf{e}_{z}\cdot (\boldsymbol{\sigma} \times
\mathbf{d}_{i,j})c_{j}^{\phantom{\dagger}}+h.c.$$ (*the final answer is known*). I cannot understand how we get the vector product through this procedure.  Can someone help me with this?

Comment: note that $\mathbf{e}_z\cdot(\mathbf{\sigma}\times\mathbf{p})  = \sigma_x p_y - \sigma_y p_x$ which is the coupling term you have originally

Comment: You don't have to express the final result in terms of the cross product, but it is a nice compact notation. Just evaluate $(\sigma \times {\bf d})_z$ to get the result in terms of annihilation and creation operators.

Comment: Thanks a lot! As I understand, this notation uses  to indicate the hopping direction?

Comment: The hopping is in the $xy$ plane, i.e. perpendicular to $e_z$. $i$ and $j$ are nearest-neighbor lattice sites, so in a square lattice $i$ will have 4 neighbors: 2 in the $x$-direction and 2 in the $y$-direction.